# Plotting in terms of odd variables

Tags: plotting

Trying to replicate [image]

Current Code:

```
M[o_, p_] = M_ 0 (1 - o/p)^(1/3);
Plot[M[o_, p_], {o/p, 0, 1}, {M, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Where did this plot come from? Always give a reference if you are putting something you did not produce yourself.

Comment: equation of interest is: M/M_0 = (1-(t/t_0))^(1/3)

Comment: That's just `Plot[(1 - t)^(1/3), {t, 0, 1}]`, then.

Comment: geez.... im trying to think of a way to use symbols to make a face-palm emjoi... thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non trivial aspects (for me) necessary to reproduce that [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) are:

[`TraditionalForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html), [`RotateLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateLabel.html) and selectively turning on/off each side of [`Frame`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html).

```
Plot[
 (1 - t)^(1/3)
 , {t, 0, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> Red
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , FrameLabel -> {TraditionalForm[t/Subscript[t, 0]], 
   TraditionalForm[M/Subscript[M, 0]]}
 , Frame -> {True, True, False, False}
 , RotateLabel -> False
 ]
```

[image]